# Python Regex separating txt files into paragraphs

Tags: python, regex, text

Is there a way to use regular expressions to to separate a txt file into paragraphs?

As an example, if this was my text file:

```
They call for you: The general who became a slave; the slave who became a gladiator; the gladiator who defied an      Emperor. Striking story.

Watch your thoughts, for they will become actions. Watch your actions, for they'll become...habits. Watch your habits for they will forge your character. Watch your character, for it will make your destiny.
```

I would expect that the \s is involved here but how to you decide to only look for newlines in regex and not whitespace?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regexp, simply use split:

```
 a="""1....
 2....
 3...."""
 print map(lambda x:x.strip(),a.split("\n"))
```

NB:

- I use strip to remove any leading / trailing space (including \r on windows)
- there is no need to use re.split as you can split on a simple character